# Haskell, algorithms and school

Tags: haskell

I am starting to doubt if my plan of getting into Haskell and functional programming by using Haskell for my next course on algorithms is a good one.

To get some Haskell lines under my belt I started trying to implement some simple algos. First: Gale-Shapley for the Stable Marriage Problem. Having not yet gotten into monads, all that mutable state looks daunting, so instead I used the characterization of stable matchings as fixed-points of a mapping on the lattice of semi-matchings. It was fun, but its no longer Gale-Shapley and the complexity isn't nice (those chains in the lattice can get pretty long apparently :)

Next up I have the algorithm for Closest Pair of points in the plane, but am stuck on getting the usual  O(n*log n) complexity because I can't work out how to get a set-like data structure with O(1) checking for membership.

So my question is: Can one in general implement most algorithms eg. Dijkstra, Ford-Fulkerson (Gale-Shapley !?) getting the complexities from procedural implementations if one gets a better command of Haskell and functional programming in general ?

Comment: Just ask lambdabot. Q: Can Haskell do xyz? A: Yes! Haskell can do that!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This probably can't be answered in general. A lot of standard algorithms are designed around mutability, and translations exist in some cases, not in others. Sometimes alternate algorithms exist that give equivalent performance characteristics, sometimes you really do need mutability.

A good place to start, if you want understanding of how to approach algorithms in this setting, is Chris Okasaki's book [Purely Functional Data Structures](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521663504). The book is an expanded version of his thesis, which is [available online in PDF format](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf).

If you want help with specific algorithms, such as the O(1) membership checking (which is actually misleading--there's no such thing, such data structures usually have something like O(k) where k is the size of elements being stored) you'd be better off asking that as a specific, single question instead of a very general question like this.

Comment: Well, you could mention it only if you aware of it. And not everyone is. Knowledge -> reputation, essential formula of SO :)

Comment: Thanks. I have added that book to my ever growing wish list of books. I will perhaps reconsider choosing a different functional language although my main motivation for choosing Haskell in the first place, besides it looking like tons of fun for a math guy, was that it seems hard to chicken out and write procedural-like code.

Comment: @user847614: Be sure to read his thesis anyway--it still has lots of useful info, and is very approachable. Anyway, Haskell has plenty of ways to do things both in pure functional style and with controlled access to mutable data. For instance, if you want key/value lookup linear in key length, you can use either mutable hash tables or pure tries/radix trees.

Comment: You can always emulate an imperative algorithm that assumes mutable state in an immutable world by emulating mutable variables with a tree-based lookup table, at the cost of a `O(log n)` factor. And this `O(log n)` slowdown is provably the best you can do in a strict language with no mutation. However, in call-by-need languages, we have a limited form of mutation available to us in the form of thunk evaluation, so while the upper bound holds, the argument used to establish the lower bound doesn't apply. So in general you can get within `O(log n)`, and sometimes you can get all the way there.

Comment: @Edward Kmett: Would be interesting to read the proof. Have you got a reference ?

Comment: [Pippinger](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall03/cs528/handouts/Pure%20Versus%20Impure%20LISP.pdf) and [Ben-Amram and Galil](http://www2.mta.ac.il/~amirben/downloadable/jacm.ps.gz) provide the proof in a strict setting, while [Bird, Jones and de Moor](ftp://ftp.comlab.ox.ac.uk/pub/Documents/techpapers/Geraint.Jones/FP-1-96.ps.Z) provide a counter example of an algorithm that can run with the same asymptotics in a call-by-need language as a strict language with mutation, but runs slower in a strict language without mutation.

Comment: One important point re: Okasaki.  One of the lovely benefits of purely functional data structures is *persistence* in the sense that unlike traditional mutable data structures, the old version of a purely functional data structure is still available for further operations.  This is a feature that is sometimes required and that could be expensive to retrofit onto a mutable data structure.  So it's apples and oranges.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have the ST monad in Haskell you can do anything with mutable state at the same speed of an imperative language. To the outside it can have a non-monadic interface.
See for instance Launchbury and Peyton-Jones: "Lazy functional state threads"
http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=178246

Answer (score 0):

[Existence proof](https://github.com/mcandre/left4deadrl/blob/master/left4deadrl.hs#L349) for implementing algorithms with mutable data structures. Just recurse over an IO record. In this case, a Game record that holds the relevant variables.